InDesign: Imported text overrides my font styles, even with "Remove Styles and Formatting for Text and Tables" checked
I've been dealing with this issue for months, and it sometimes doubles my work time on things that shouldn't be taking so long. It's a bit of an essay, so here's a bulleted list to easily show the main issues:

the manuscript's font (TNR) is preserved on random paragraphs on import, creating an override for my Baskerville paragraph style.
there's random instances of Arial Unicode MS buried in the italics sections, causing a missing font error, even though that font isn't present in the original manuscript doc.
the imported text is registered randomly as multiple different languages, creating spellcheck issues and even formatting issues.
I check "Remove Styles and Formatting for Text and Tables" and check "Preserve Local Overrides" to maintain the italics, but don't know how to tell it to ignore everything else.
my workaround (importing the text, Find and Replace the italics with a character style, then clearing the remaining overrides) stopped working, and now F&R just deletes chunks of italics with no explanation.

I have a Word document from a client of his entire book manuscript. It's in the default (TNR) font, and he has minimal formatting done to it to help me see where headings and blockquotes should go. He also has quite a few italics, bold, and even underlines (I know—but he likes them, and I'm not going to argue).
I like breaking the manuscript up by chapters, and then I Place them into InDesign. Almost always, most of the text remains in TNR despite setting my paragraph style as Baskerville. It shows that there's an override, but obviously if I clear the entire import of overrides, I lose his italics, bold, underline, etc. (more on that in a second). TNR and Baskerville are close enough that I can't always see when it does it—it's random. Sometimes a paragraph will follow the style correctly, but many don't, and I can't find the pattern.
A follow-up problem that seems to be related: for this particular manuscript, I also have a strange missing font in many of the italicized block quotes. The spaces between random words are in a font that doesn't have an italics style (Arial Unicode MS). The weird thing is that—because of the first issue—I ensured that everything in his manuscript was in a default body font, and Arial Unicode MS is nowhere in the original manuscript I'm importing from.
Oh, and the document also imports as different languages. In the Character Panel on the right, random words will be listed as Turkey, or Greek, or Arabic, or France. Somehow this messes up the formatting because when I change it back to English USA, the words jump around on the page. It also thinks random words are spelled wrong because it's crossing them against the wrong dictionary.
When I Place a Word doc, I make sure "Remove Styles and Formatting for Text and Tables" is checked in the Import Options, but I leave "Preserve Local Overrides." This is supposed to keep the italics, bold, and underlines, which I can then convert into character styles using Find and Replace. Flushing all those styles and doing them manually would take forever and open up the risk of me missing one, so I don't want that, but I'm thinking it's also pulling fonts over with that. I just don't know what the client is doing to his manuscript to make it happen. He's not tech savvy, but there's not anything weird that I can see at a glance.
In the case of this particular manuscript, I highlighted all the text and changed everything to a body style, thinking maybe there was a weird style I couldn't see. I did set everything to TNR, again thinking there might have been some weird font trapped in the document, but why would that be carrying over? How can I just tell InDesign to not care about the font? Why doesn't it see it as a default? (And just to be clear, previous manuscripts had the same TNR issue without me setting the font myself, so the issue is still there regardless.)
I've been using a workaround that's worked okay until today. Normally I'll Place the chapter, do a Find and Replace of the italics/bold/underlines with their correlated character styles, then do a clear override of the entire chapter. It's annoying and feels unnecessary. Today, though, Finding and Replacing the override italics with the character italics actually deletes the text instead. I checked my character style—nothing about it should be doing that. And again, it's random. It deletes chunks of italics, not the whole paragraph. It feels like there's some kind of invisible style that's interfering with things.
This client has a lot of manuscripts, so this is going to be a real pain if I can't figure it out. And his manuscripts aren't the only ones who have random TNR overrides and foreign languages—his are just the worst. I also don't feel comfortable posting screenshots of his manuscript online or sharing the file (contract NDA-related stuff). I just need to figure out what in the manuscript is causing these issues so I can 1) fix the manuscripts I already have, and 2) instruct future clients to format them in a way that won't send InDesign into a seizure.

I use a similar approach and have more or less the same problems. Word just sucks. Even when I try to make a tightly formatted Word doc from scratch myself, there are strange inconsistencies. The part about chunks of italic disappearing sounds strange though. Are you sure you aren't changing to spaces or something? I don't really have enough tips to write a real answer. I normally just brute force it. One thing though: Sometimes it helps to save the Word doc as .doc instead of .docx. Try that.

I save all Word files as a Plain Text file. Then place the plain text into InDesign.. Plain text is just that, plain. No font, style, color at all. Then I merely look at the Word file for reference if necessary, in order to reset font styles after I've imported the plain text. I never place Word files directly into InDesign. As you've found, it almost always screws up styles somewhere.. or color... For me, it takes far less time to merely go through and reset italics, bold, etc than it does to find them and correct styles issues after placing a Word file.

@Scott, I've done that as well but if you have an 800 page academic text with footnotes and thousands of italicized word you have to make the import of the word document work somehow.

The funny thing is though, that if I convert a markdown file to docx using Pandoc, there seems to be zero problems with importing into InDesign. The formatting is consistent. (Too bad my clients don't know about markdown.)

meh... I'd still rather use plain text in most cases. But... if for some reason I must place a Word file (can't think of any reason) .... find the first instance of a style, create new style, trash old style telling IDD to replace with new style - will work in a pinch. But Interesting.. will have to see about Pandoc next time.

Yeah, I'm dyslexic, so I don't trust myself to find every italics in a massive scroll of text. I've done it before, but I don't like it, and it takes just as much time as messing with the quirks imo.

Found another workaround tho—Because of that missing Arial font, InDesign gives me the option to replace it, along with any other fonts in the doc, and that's where I can see TNR and others. So every chapter I just go through and replace them all with Baskerville. Fixed a lot of issues, though sadly not the random languages, so I have to remember to change it before I start formatting. (Seriously what is with the language thing??)

There will ALWAYS be issues importing from Word to InDesign, period.
